Can you be a determinist while thinking laws are just descriptions?
Suppose that you think laws are descriptive and not prescriptive. In other words, you think that laws merely describe what happens and not that events in the world directly follow or are prescribed by these laws.
Now, even if everything that you observed in the world so far could be described by laws, how can you be a consistent determinist? Even if you knew everything about the universe today, and all its properties, you can only predict what happens tomorrow if you think that tomorrow’s events are described by the same laws you just made your calculation with.
But if you think laws are descriptive, you have no reason to think that those same laws will remain tomorrow. There is nothing that “determines” this constancy and hence tomorrow becomes contingent despite all your knowledge, not necessary. But if tomorrow is contingent and you have no principle by which to rule out other possibilities (such as the laws changing tomorrow), then how is this determinism?
On the other hand, if you believe that laws are prescriptive and that the reason why every day is the same is because laws are a fundamental fabric of the universe, then you don’t have to explain why tomorrow stays the same as today. The explanation for this is that laws are prescriptive.

Hume was just that. According to Hume, basing what one thinks on reason alone gives reason way too much credit. After all, "reason is, and ought only to be, the slave of the passions". One can believe it because "there is some other principle, which determines him to form such a conclusion.... It is more comfortable to the ordinary wisdom of nature to secure so necessary an act of the mind, by some instinct or mechanical tendency...  so she has implanted in us an instinct, which carries forward the thought in a correspondent course to that which she has established among external objects."

There are the laws we apply when solving a physics problem, for example Newton's law of universal gravitation, and the actual regularity of behavior that we observe. The latter is usually seen as a universal and immovable fact, while the former is only descriptive (which is made evident by the fact that they can be wrong, like Newton's law was found to be). There is no logical contradiction in stating that the laws of physics are only descriptive while the actual behavior of matter is deterministic, because they are not the same thing.

There is of course no logical contradiction in that but no where in the post do I state that so that’s a bit of an irrelevant point. The point is that if laws are merely descriptions, then we don’t have an explanation for the regularities. Regularities staying and remaining the way they are tomorrow becomes a brute fact.

Then i don't understand how one can't be determinist if they believe the laws of physics are descriptive. Someone who believes in determinism as a brute fact is still a determinist. Note also that someone who thinks physical laws are prescriptive does not have any explanation either for their existence, unless they posit the existence of some deity making the prescription but that's another problem altogether.

Yes both resort to ultimate explanations but a determinist only has one brute fact which is that there are prescriptive laws and just that fact explains why the regularities stay the same every day. Without that, every moment the regularities stay the same is a brute fact. So believing that laws are descriptive involves many more brute facts

This reminds me Kiblinger's description of Peirce's response:"He argues that determinism requires no less swallowing of arbitrary givenness in the form of “immutable and ultimate facts” for which no account can be offered (6:41). The only difference is that in this case the facts are all given up front at once — a bitter pill that can be swallowed and then forgotten only at the expense of self-delusion." Brute facts or entities can always be packaged, which is why 'counting' them in Occam's razor is of little use.

@Conifold Very interesting! I feel like the response just says that it swallows all the facts at once without explaining why. Do you have any further resources in regards to counting of brute facts or in general how brute facts are examined especially with regards to determinism. I was reading the SEP paper on the philosophy of facts which has a small section on brute facts. Either way, this is something I’ve been thinking about for ages. Quantum mechanics is a good example. Which theory would have less brute facts? A deterministic or indeterministic one?

I’ll read the linked work

There's actually a kind of beautifully deep ambiguity in the word "law". When people talk about "the laws of physics", for example, they don't always mean the same thing. Some people mean "the laws you learn in a physics class". Some people mean something more like "the actual ontological reason, which we're ignorant of, for why matter behaves the way it does". I think it's important to be careful about the word 'law' in these conversations.

When it comes to the first kind of law, the kind of law you learn in a physics class, you can ABSOLUTELY believe they're just descriptions and be a determinist.

When it comes to the second type, not believing in that kind of law is like saying "I don't believe there's a reason why matter behaves in these consistent ways", and if you don't believe there's an underlying reason why it does... Idk, I find it hard to understand how such a person would be a 'determinist', but that's just based on my intuition.

We can say that this is the search for secular harmony with the laws of nature with the principle of general validity. There is no need for explanation, but philosophical thought can be explained. The person is very prone to corruption. For those who want to go in a different direction from the intersection. :)

I'm not sure there are any Physicists who would follow the position described as "prescriptivist" in this question. The laws of physics are a human construction describing the observed behaviour of the universe; the things they describe the behaviour cannot possibly have their behaviour prescribed by them.

What causes their behavior?

Hi. Are you talking about legal laws or about physical laws? If physical laws, could you please edit the question to make that clear in the very first sentence?

Yes, it's easy.
There's (at least) two ways of doing so:
You could postulate that there are in fact underlying laws of the universe, but these are too complex or obscure to be grasped by human intellect. Therefore, the physical laws that physicists come up with are only approximations, in much the same way that Newtonian mechanics is an approximation for Einsteinian relativity. The true laws of physics are prescriptive, but the ones that we know are descriptive. This kind of determinism would mean if you had both perfect knowledge of the present state of the universe and perfect knowledge of the true laws of physics (not merely approximations) then you could predict the future.
The second possibility is theism. The properties of nature and the sequence of events have all been determined by God. However, since God is above the laws of physics, this means that they are not absolute rules and can be violated at any time that God wishes (this is what we call a miracle). Thus, according to theism, physical laws are not hard rules, but rather merely the general pattern that the material world follows. [This is the normal view among Christians, though different denominations may ascribe varying levels of power to the human will.]

It will help to clarify your question if you distinguish three different kinds of law - and two different kinds of natural law.
This answer states the three different kinds of law quite clearly:-


Empirical laws are verified /falsified
Mathematical1 laws are discovered and applied
Legal laws are enforced and broken


One could put this by saying that when a legal law is broken, we look at the offender, but when a natural law is broken, we look at the law. We can describe the difference by saying that legal laws prescribe and natural laws describe.
However, there was a time when the belief that natural laws were made (and enforced) by God and it seems reasonable to suppose that we have continued to use the phrase even though that belief is no longer dominant.
(Well, there is a complication, because there is, in jurisprudence, a sense of natural law that is much more like legal laws. These laws were identified by Roman jurists in the second century CE. They called them ius gentium which can be translated as "universal rights" or "universal law". They don't fit neatly into either the category of legal laws or of natural laws.)
So the question becomes whether a description determines what it is a description of. So now we have to consider the ambiguities of "determine". To save time and space, I refer you to The Cambridge Dictionary definition. You will see that there are some senses in which a description can be said to determine what it is a description of. But the relevant sense of determine in Determinism is "control directly". In that sense a description does not determine what it is a description of.

You cannot be a determinist at all.
Determinism is just an idea of an imaginary system where every event is completely determined by prior events.
Determinism is not a proposition, a theory, a belief or even a philosophical standpoint. Determinism does not describe reality or explain anything. Determinism is neither true nor false, there is nothing to believe, nothing to argue for or against.
Determinism is nothing but a practical tool in classical physics.
